# Successor beneficiary to inherited IRA - RMD calculation?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, rmd

There are so many moving parts to this in the tax code... I keep thinking I understand it but now I'm not sure.

My grandmother died in March 2017, age 93.  She had been taking required distributions based on her life expectancy, but the remaining money passed to my father.  He was 69 in 2017.  He started taking RMDs, I believe, once he turned 72, using the age tables.

He died in late 2022, with me as the successor beneficiary.

As I understand it:

1. We have 10 years to empty this account, meaning 2032.
2. We are required to still take an RMD from this account.  We did not do so last year as the IRS waived the penalties. I believe they then extended this through 2023, but for purposes of this question, let's assume they hadn't.

In terms of the RMD calculation:

1. Take the value of the account at the end of 2022
2. Divide this by the life expectancy factor from the IRS charts.  **THIS IS MY QUESTION** -- Who's age?  My father's?  Or mine?  Do I start with the 2022 table and subtract 1?

I'd just like to understand the actual RMD calculation as it applies in this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your grandmother's IRA, it should be your father's remaining life expectancy.

See the [IRS publication 590-B](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2022_publink100090143):

> As discussed in [Death of a beneficiary](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2022_publink100095122), earlier, if the designated beneficiary dies before his or her portion of the account is fully distributed, continue to use the designated beneficiary’s remaining life expectancy to determine the amount of distributions. However, any remaining balance in the account must be distributed within 10 years of the beneficiary's death.